# (Java) why is Math.ceil(15/10) is 1.0 and not 2.0?

Tags: java, casting, double, integer-division

Why is `Math.ceil(15/10)` 1.0 and not 2.0 ? 
When I run instead `Math.ceil((double)15/10)` I get 2.0 as expected.

Comment: use `Math.ceil(15f/10)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because dividing an integer by another integer gives you an integer : `15/10` is `1`.

From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) :

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for
>   operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion
>   (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible
>   while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d|
>   and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n
>   and d have opposite signs.

You should use `Math.ceil(15.0/10)` or `Math.ceil(15f/10)` (the first one using doubles, the  second one float).